# Limit of an exponent function

Tags: calculus, limits

maybe you can help me solve this limit? Thanks!

$$ \lim_ {x \to \infty} \left( 1+ \frac {1}{x^2}\right)^{3x-4}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will have more chances to get an answer if you show what you have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^{3x-4}=\left(\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^{x^2}\right)^{\frac{3x-4}{x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**
Let 
$$
f(x)=\left( 1+ \frac {1}{x^2}\right)^{3x-4}
$$

Take the logarithm to get that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\log f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{3x-4}{x^2}\times\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^{-2})-\log 1}{x^{-2}}
$$
The first limit should be easity to compute, the second follows from the definition of the derivative.